# Плавная прокрутка якорей

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, прокрутка

Всем привет,
Я использую этот простенький код для плавного скролла по якорям и всё это чудесно работает:

```
function scrollNav() {
  $('a[href*="#"]').click(function(){
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top - 73
    }, 400);
    return false;
  });
}
scrollNav();
```

НО,  на разрешениях 1023 - 1367
был применен медиа запрос для более читабельного вида сайта :

```
@media (min-width: 1023px) and (max-width: 1367px) {
    body {
      zoom: 0.8;
    }
}
```

И вот как раз скролл по якорям на этих резолюциях работает некорректно.

Может кто подскажет как решить эту задачу?

Спасибо за любую помощь

Comment: Добавьте поддержку мозилы `-moz-transform: scale(0.8);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

умножать прокрутку тоже на 0.8 при этих разрешениях

```js
function scrollNav() {
  $('a[href*="#"]').click(function(){
  
    let scrollTop = $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top;
    if($(window).width() > 1023 && $(window).width() < 1376){
      scrollTop = scrollTop*0.8;
    }
    
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: scrollTop - 73
    }, 400);
    return false;
  });
}
scrollNav();
```

Comment: Спасибо, правда Ваш вариант не сработал, потому я немного подправил ответ.